# How can I find database elements into a text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

Let's assume I have a food app. It is build with RoR and using Postgresql. In it, user can add receipe in a text_field:

> Preheat oven to 350 degrees F (175 degrees C).
>
> Cream together the butter, white sugar, and brown sugar until smooth. Beat in the eggs one at a time, then stir in the vanilla. Dissolve baking soda in hot water. Add to batter along with salt. Stir in flour, chocolate chips, and nuts. Drop by large spoonfuls onto ungreased pans.
>
> Bake for about 10 minutes in the preheated oven, or until edges are nicely browned.

When submitting the form, I'd like to recognize all the ingredients and see if there is a match with the table ingredients of my database.

In other words, I would like a function that gets in input the text written by the user and in output a list of objects 'ingredient' that are present in the table ingredients of my database (for instance, butter, white sugar, eggs...)

I really don't know how to do it. The only idea I have, is to split the text by word and do a query one by one to search them into the table ingredients. But I fear it is going to be really slow.
And what if an ingredient is composed of 2 words or more, or if there is a typing error or if there is a dash, a cap, plurals?

Any idea? Any gem or build in library that could do the job?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Hi, asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stackoverflow. I believe that solution to your need without library is a bit too much to ask in a single question.

Comment: It's hard to decide why to vote for closing this question: 1) too broad 2) asking for a library.

Comment: Try from the other end: load all known ingredients and try to find them in that recipe. This assumes absense of typos and some normalization of input (making it all lowercase, for example). But in general case (recipe in, ingredients out) this sounds like it's definitely in NLP realm (natural language processing). Which is to say, off-topic as "too broad".

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that it was a sacrilege to ask for a library... I won't do it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the text in `input` variable, you can do it with a single regular expression.

First, build the array or all the ingredients (in real life this would be a database query.)

```
ingredients = %w|butter white\ sugar eggs foobar|
#⇒ ["butter", "white sugar", "eggs", "foobar"]
```

Now with a help of [`Regexp#union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) we might select all the matches:

```
input.scan(Regexp.union(ingredients))
#⇒ ["butter", "white sugar", "eggs"]
```

Probably you want the regular expression to be case-insensitive, etc, but the main idea is that.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think that when but it makes perfectly sense! This is exactly what I want.